# How to set "hg diff" output shows in gvim?

Tags: mercurial, diff, vim

I use mercurial and I want to see modified change in Vim or GVim.
Normally there is `hg diff` which show the modified changes in diff format.
but I want to see it in Vim as the original version and modified version side-by-side.

I try extdiff in [ExtdiffExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) but it doesn't work and gvim open some blank file.

I know there is `gvim -d localfile otherfile` but I don't know how to config mercurial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this: [Using vimdiff to view single diffs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UsingVimdiffForSingleDiffs)

```
hg cat <filename> | vim - -c  ":vert diffsplit <filename>" -c "map q :qa!<CR>";
```

Comment: Links are not considered a good answer overall. Please summarize/further describe the content at that link.

Comment: From the linked page: `hg cat <filename> | vim - -c  ":vert diffsplit <filename>" -c "map q :qa!<CR>";` I'm not sure it is a good solution.

Answer (score 31):

If you're fine with vim, I'm been using this in my `~/.hgrc` for months without problems

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.vimdiff =

[alias]
vi  = vimdiff
vim = vimdiff
```

Then you just use

```
hg vimdiff somefile
```

The `[alias]` section is optional, but it's nice to have.

I'm using v1.4.2, FWIW.

Comment: Works good for me, and much simpler than the solution linked to by @rcs. Thanks. +1

Comment: If you prefer to use GVim: Change `cmd.vimdiff =` to `cmd.vimdiff = gvimdiff`

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you for the vim part, but in mercurial, to get the content of a file in the parent changest, you'll do `hg cat path/to/my/file.ext`

Answer (score 0):

On OSX when using MacVim (and homebrew):

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s mvim gvimdiff
```

edit~/.hgrc

```
[extdiff]
cmd.gdiff = gvimdiff
opts.gdiff = -f
```

then to use:

```
hg gdiff somefile.cpp
```